# Advice on buying a PC to run Adobe software

Tags: adobe-illustrator, hardware-recommendation

I start studying Graphic Design and I am using Illustrator CC but I have a lots of lags when using it with my laptop. My laptop is an Asus N53SN with 16Gb Ram, 512 SSD, and Quad Core processor Intel i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00 GHz, with Intel Graphics and NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 550M CUDA 2GB. But when using Illustrator CC it seems not to work very well and I get some lags and sometimes the program closes.

I would like to know what is best specifications to the Adobe CC suite. I plan to buy a good desktop for this and my budget is between £1.000-1.200. At some point I will also be using Premiere Pro and After Effects.

Comment: What you have is more than enough. Sounds like you could use a system cleanup/reinstall windows/etc. The specs are very good even for a professional, use the money for something else.

Answer (score 1):

> "Asus N53SN with 16Gb Ram, 512 SSD, and Quad Core processor Intel i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00 GHz, with Intel Graphics and NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 550M CUDA 2GB."

I'd start with your current laptop, it's plenty powerful. Based on those specs you should be absolutely fine for anything you are doing while studying GD.

First try adding more RAM. 16GB should be fine, but more is better. And make sure you are running 64 Bit versions of CC and Windows to take advantage of all that RAM. With the exception of the RAM, your machine is more powerful than my 2009 MacPro tower that I run at home with CC running quite comfortably.

Next maybe do a Full Clean / Install of the OS and CC. A fresh start always helps my machines run better. Make sure you back up first!

If you still want a tower, I'm sure someone else here will post a spec sheet you should look for. I use only Macs, so I'm not sure I'll be much help there.